# Obtaining view controllers of tabbar control

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, delegates, protocols

I have a tabbar navigation controller, and I would like to set up a protocol in one view controller and set its delegate in another view controller.  How would I get the view controller pointer of the delegating view controller to the delegate view controller?

Comment: viewControllers property of UITabbarController?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
MyDelegatingViewController *delegatingController = [myTabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
MyDelegateViewController *delegateController = [myTabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
delegatingController.delegate = delegateController;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ole, thank you.  Your post got me half way there.  I didn't realize at first that viewControllers returns the Navigation Controller of the view controllers.  Once I realized this, I can then drill into the child view controller of the navigation controller:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UINavigationController *navController = [appDelegate.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
myViewController = (MyViewController*)[navController topViewController];
self.myViewController.delegate = self;
```